# Does a thread - run at the same speed (in relation to all other processor tasks)?

Tags: multithreading, performance, time, processor

I am wondering if a thread are running the same speed in relation to all other threads in a computer? They all run on the same processor after all so if a thread "lags" - I think that would mean that everything preformed by the processor lagged at that moment? I think this a correct assumption? Or am I wrong?

Comment: What operating system? What threading system? What CPU/architecture? Are you talking about operating system, library or cpu threads? What is another "processor task"?

Comment: In general, whenever a thread is running, it executes code at the same number of cycles per second as any other thread. However, the OS may decide to let one thread run less often or for less time than another depending on whether it is waiting for I/O, or is prioritised differently by your application. In addition, the CPU sometimes speeds up and slows down because of TurboBoost and power-saving techniques.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are several *layers* to think about: the concept "thread" exists within your programming language, or maybe within some "framework" of your language; within the operating system and even within the hardware.

The key thing is: in the end, down in the real hardware, the CPU simply has various elements of its pipes, registers, ... duplicated. Meaning: each thread is running on its own distinct hardware; and that hardware is (most likely) identical for each thread. Therefore: all threads should be moving with the same speed (the clock speed of the CPU that is).

But of course, there are other concepts that come into play; for example thread *priority*. Most operating system allow you to say: "this thread is more important than another thread". And that means that the more important thread *might* receive more CPU cycles than others. But that also depends on the overall *load* the CPU is currently facing.

Finally: you have to be clear about terminology. A thread is nothing but an abstraction for some "thread of activity". A thread is *meaningless* until you consider that it is executing certain code. So a thread itself is not "lagging"; but the code it is executing might for example lead to a lot of *waiting* (for example when doing IO). And then you *observe* the thread "not moving". But that isn't caused by the "speed" which the thread runs with, but with what the thread is actually doing!

Regarding priorities: that very much depends on the operating system / framework. Basically there would be one component measuring "consumption" and making decisions on that. The easiest model is that threads receive time slices; and of course: then some manager can decide how to distribute the available time slices to the threads waiting for processor time. You might look [here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/threads/priority.html) (pretty old material, but still a good read); or [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workload_Manager) for a specific implementation example.

---

Comment: The priority factor is a good point. Do you happen to know how it works? If we have a thread A with low priority (that gets 5% of the cpu power - I assume thats how it works?). While A is doing its job - another thread B with hight priority starts (and should be getting 10 % of the CPU). Can operating system take 3 % from thread A - lowering it to 2% in creation of B thread?

Comment: When you increase the priority of a thread it just makes it more likely to run more often, it doesn't change the processing *"speed"*. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

Comment: @Lealo I updated my answer according - but please understand: whole books are written about such topics. Dont expect to cover all of that in a single answer. Besides, is there anything else to make my answer upvote/accept worthy in your eyes ... now that you reached upvote level?